# Writing data to binary file after reading the data from binary file in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell

Can anyone let me know how to read a binary file for some data and write that data to the new binary file in shell script and so on? I am using Linux.

Note: `cat file1 > file2` : not required as this writes the complete data.

Requirement: reading some data and writing and reading again and writing..

```
while read -n1 ch
do
   
    cat $ch > $output   # Tried this, showing error. While writing the data after reading, cat command throws error : No such file or directory.
        
done < $filename
```

Comment: What is `ch`? Is it a file name? Are you just looking for `printf '%s\n' "$ch" >> "$output"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary data"? Bash `read` is intended for line-based text. It skips NUL characters completely, and it returns an empty string for newline regardless of the IFS value (although -N1 does return actual newlines). printf won't output NULL either. So your binary file will be mangled. Also, using `> file` in a loop just rewrites the file per character, and `>> file` opens and closes the file for each char. Use `> file` *outside* the loop (after the `done`).

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is a command used to con**cat**enate files and, by extension, also used to print the contents of a single file to standard output. All `cat` does is take a file or whatever is fed into its standard input stream and print it out. You It doesn't print its arguments, like `echo` or a `print` statement in other languages, that isn't what it's for.

So you're using the wrong tool for the job here. You want `echo` which prints out whatever you give it adding a newline at the end (usually, and by default) or, [better and safer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222) especially for binary data, `printf`:

```
while read -r -n1 ch
do
    printf '%s\n' "$ch" >> "$output"
done < "$filename"
```

Note the `-r` which tells `read` not to interpret backslashes as escapes, the use of `>>` instead of `>` since with `>` you would be overwriting `$output` on each iteration and would only ever see the last character read and the use of quotes around your variables to [protect them from split+glob expansion by the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222).